# jquery tabselect not working when clicking on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery tabselect plugin. Here is [link](http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/tabselect.php)

When i select tab then it should fire alert. But thats not happening.

I wrote below code

```
$('#langtabs span.active').each(function(){
        alert("d");
        var lang=$(this).text();
        select_lang+=','+lang;
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yun97ecf/23/)

Can someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **onChange** event, like this:

```
$('#langtabs').tabSelect({
        tabElements: languages,
        selectedTabs: [ 'de', 'en' ],  
        onChange: function(selection){
            alert(selection);
        }
    });
```

[check updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yun97ecf/26/)

Comment: here is another question if you can answer .. its again based on tabselect 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076086/deselect-all-tab-jquery-tabselect

Comment: @Happy, ok i answered ;)