# deselect all tab jquery tabselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery tabselect plugin. Here is [link](http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/tabselect.php)

I wish to deselect all selected tabs on button click event.

I wrote below code on button click but nothing happens

```
$('#langtabs').tabSelect({
        tabElements: mydata,
        //selectedTabs: ['de', 'en'],
        selectedTabs: []
    });
```

Can someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using this method:

```
$('#langtabs').data('tabSelect').deselectAll();
```

So create a button in HTML

```
<button id="deselect">DESELECT ALL</button>
```

then in jQuery:

```
$('#deselect').on('click', function(){
   $('#langtabs').data('tabSelect').deselectAll();
});
```

Check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yun97ecf/33/)

Comment: can you answer this as well ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077680/hide-data-description-option-in-msdropdown